# .htaccess not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just live my website. Website Link is : http://cmexpertiseinfotech.in/pos1/
it's working fine in localhost.My .htaccess file is,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /pos
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

So in htaccess i'm checking that rewrite mode enable or not ? But it's not working **it's showing 404 page.** 
I have put my .htaccess of main directory like this,

**Directory Structure**,

```
-application
     -.htaccess // this .htaccess has no content (Deny from all )
-system
-user_guide
-public
-.htaccess // this .htaccess's content is show above.
```

**base_url()** is :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://cmexpertiseinfotech.in/pos/';
```

**EDIT :**
I just request for rewrite mode enable to my head but it takes 1-2 days so i'm trying another thing and I just removed .htaccess file from project on root directory.

This is working. please visit this link : http://cmexpertiseinfotech.in/pos/index.php/welcome/index.

but this is not working.
http://cmexpertiseinfotech.in/pos/index.php/home/login.

Controller :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

View : Login.php

```
<h1> Login </h1>
```

Comment: It kinda does what is says on the tin. You ask it to show a 404 if mod_rewrite is not installed. It shows a 404. Why are we not concluding that mod_rewrite is not installed?

Comment: thank you for the reply . i'm poor in .htaccess brother so please guide me what to do here ?RewriteEngine On means it's enable so what is the issue here i didn't understand

Comment: Aha! I understand the confusion. I'll put my response in an answer, so I can format it better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up two questions here:

1. Is mod_rewrite installed/enabled ?
2. Is the Rewrite Engine on/active ?

This line checks if it's installed and loaded:
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`.

Only if it's loaded does Apache then turn it on with:
`RewriteEngine On`.

Since it seems not to be installed or enabled here, you need to solve that. But you (or someone) will need root permission on the server, and then you need to find the Apache configuration file.

**Is this hosted by a provider**

You need to ask them to enable mod_rewrite

**If you can get to the file**

Unless Apache was very restrictively installed, you should be able to find the following line:

`#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Enable it by removing the `#`. Then restart Apache.

It's hard to go into specific commands here, because there's so much variation in how Apache is installed.

Comment: Ohk.. Thank you for the reply brother. I'm checking that i have root permission or not. I have host gator as a provider. How can I check root permission in host gator ???

Comment: I think that's a question for the support desk of Host Gator. No-one on Stack Overflow is affiliated with them.

Comment: Ohk brother i'm raising a ticket for host gator about this issue of enabling the  rewrite mode. will let you know about that thank you for the reply.